# Python - printing out a trie in alphabetically sorted order with a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, trie, nltk-book

I'm working my way through the [NLTK book](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch04.html#exercises) by Bird, Klein, and Loper and I'm stuck on a problem.  I'm working through the book for my own personal enrichment, and not for a class.

The problem I'm stuck on is 4.29:

***Write a recursive function that pretty prints a trie in alphabetically sorted order, e.g.:***

`chair: 'flesh'
---t: 'cat'
--ic: 'stylish'
---en: 'dog'`

I'm using this code from the book to create the trie:

```
def insert(trie, key, value):
    if key:
        first, rest = key[0], key[1:]
        if first not in trie:
            trie[first] = {}
        insert(trie[first], rest, value)
    else:
        trie['value'] = value

trie = {}
insert(trie, 'chat', 'cat')
insert(trie, 'chien', 'dog')
insert(trie, 'chair', 'flesh')
insert(trie, 'chic', 'stylish')
```

I modified an answer from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36977856/9097207) for a function that recursively goes through the trie and pulls out the complete keys and values:

```
def trawl_trie(trie):
    unsorted = []
    for key, value in trie.items():
        if 'value' not in key:
            for item in trawl_trie(trie[key]):
                unsorted.append(key + item)
        else:
            unsorted.append(': ' + value)

    return unsorted
```

But I'm not able to use recursion to make an alphabetical list, nor can I figure out how to use recursion to replace the duplicate parts of the keys.  The best that I can do is to create a helper function that goes through the results of the function above:

```
def print_trie(trie):

    # sort list alphabetically
    alphabetized = list(sorted(set(trawl_trie(trie))))


    print(alphabetized[0])

    # compare the 2nd item ~ to the previous one in the list.
    for k in range(1, len(alphabetized)):
        # separate words from value
        prev_w, prev_d = (re.findall(r'(\w+):', alphabetized[k - 1]), re.findall(r': (\w+)', alphabetized[k - 1]))
        curr_w, curr_d = (re.findall(r'(\w+):', alphabetized[k]), re.findall(r': (\w+)', alphabetized[k]))
        word = ''

        # find parts that match and replace them with dashes
        for i in range(min(len(prev_w[0]), len(curr_w[0]))):
            if prev_w[0][i] == curr_w[0][i]:
                word += prev_w[0][i]

        curr_w[0] = re.sub(word, '-' * len(word), curr_w[0])
        print(curr_w[0] + ": " + str(curr_d[0]))
```

This would be the output:

```
print_trie(trie)

chair: flesh
---t: cat
--ic: stylish
---en: dog
```

Does anyone know if it would be possible to get the same result with one recursive function?  Or I am stuck using a recursive function to go through the trie, and a second helper function to make everything look nice?

Cheers,

- MC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def insert(trie, key, value):
    """Insert into Trie"""
    if key:
        first, rest = key[0], key[1:]
        if first not in trie:
            trie[first] = {}
        insert(trie[first], rest, value)
    else:
        trie['value'] = value

def display(trie, s = ""):
  """Recursive function to Display Trie entries in alphabetical order"""
  first = True
  for k, v in sorted(trie.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]):
    # dictionary sorted based upon the keys
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      if first:
        prefix = s + k          # first to show common prefix
        first = False
      else:
        prefix = '-'*len(s) + k  # dashes for common prefix

      display(v, prefix)   # s+k is extending string s for display by appending current key k
    else:
      print(s, ":", v)  # not a dictionary, so print current   # not a dictionary, so print current string s and value

# Create Trie
trie = {}
insert(trie, 'chat', 'cat')
insert(trie, 'chien', 'dog')
insert(trie, 'chair', 'flesh')
insert(trie, 'chic', 'stylish')

#Display Use Recursive function (second argument will default to "" on call)
display(trie)
```

Output

```
chair : flesh
---t : cat
--ic : stylish
---en : dog
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Darryl, but I think the output should be slightly different.  I.e., if the beginning of a key has already been printed, the characters should be replaced with dashes.  E.g., chair: flesh; ---t: cat; --ic: stylish; ---en: dog.

Comment: @Sturzgefahr--thanks.  Sorry, I didn't understand the purpose of the dashes earlier.  Your post just mentioned "Write a recursive function that pretty prints a trie in alphabetically sorted order, e.g.:", but didn't explain the dashes were a common prefix.  Your modification looks good.

Comment: @Sturzgefahr--was able to accommodate your dashes with a simple modification.  See the revised solution.

Comment: @ DarrylG--thanks again for the updated code - works perfectly, and I learned a lot.  The instructions for the problem are verbatim from the NLTK book, which is infamous for poorly-worded exercises.  But you were able to write something that can output what I was looking for, so thanks again.

Comment: @Sturzgefahr--glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I modified DarrylG's answer (**thanks again!**) by adding a list of accepted keys that gets passed through the recursion and a pair of `for`-loops that iterate through this list to see if there are any common elements at the beginning of the string that can be replaced.

**Edit 11/2/19: This modification has a bug that I hadn't noticed.  It will run correctly the first time, but on subsequent runs it will replace too many characters will dashes, i.e.:**

```
----r: flesh
---t: cat
---c: stylish
----n: dog
```

```
def insert(trie, key, value):
    """Insert into Trie"""
    if key:
        first, rest = key[0], key[1:]
        if first not in trie:
            trie[first] = {}
        insert(trie[first], rest, value)
    else:
        trie['value'] = value

def display(trie, s = "", final = []):

    """Recursive function to Display Trie entries in alphabetical order"""

    for k, v in sorted(trie.items(), key = lambda x: x[0]):

        # dictionary sorted based upon the keys
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            display(v, s + k, final)   # s+k is extending string s for display by appending current key k
        else:
            # replace common elements at beginning of strings with dashes
            i = sum([any([f.startswith(string[:j]) for f in final]) for j in range(1, len(string))])
            string = '-' * i + s[i:]

            print(string + ":", v)  # not a dictionary, so print current edited s and value
            final.append(s)


# Create Trie
trie = {}
insert(trie, 'chat', 'cat')
insert(trie, 'chien', 'dog')
insert(trie, 'chair', 'flesh')
insert(trie, 'chic', 'stylish')

#Display Use Recursive function (second argument will default to "" on call)
display(trie)
```

Comment: Modified my solution to place dashes.  Let me know if the new solution is closer to what you are looking for?